# Using regex to split a sting into multiple variables SAS

Tags: regex, split, sas

I have a question regarding the usage of regex in SAS.

My dataset looks like that:

| ID | Code |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | K2K5K8F10F26F2 |
| 102 | L7P13P4 |
| 103 | L1 |

And I would like it to look like this:

| ID | Code |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | K2 |
| 101 | K5 |
| 101 | K8 |
| 101 | F10 |
| 101 | F26 |
| 101 | F2 |
| 102 | L7 |
| 102 | P13 |
| 102 | P4 |
| 103 | L1 |

At the beginning I thought that it is easier to do it first by assigning new columns and then by rows.

My attempt looks as follows:

```
proc ds2;
data Codes (overwrite=yes);
dcl char(16) code1 code2 code3 code4 code5 code6;
dcl double re;
keep code1 code2 code3 code4 code5 code6;
retain re;

 method init();
      dcl varchar(32) expression;
      expression = '/(\w+\d+)+/';
      re=prxparse(expression);
      if missing( re ) then do;
         put 'ERROR: Invalid expression ' expression;
         stop;
      end;
end;



method run();
      set mytable;
      code1 = 'ERROR';
      if prxmatch(re, Code) then
         do;
            code1=prxposn(re, 0, Code);
            code2=prxposn(re, 1, Code);
            code3=prxposn(re, 2, Code);
            code4=prxposn(re, 3, Code);
            code5=prxposn(re, 4, Code);
            code6=prxposn(re, 5, Code);
         end;
       else do;
           code1='0';
        end;
   end;
enddata;
run;
quit;

proc print data=Codes;
run;
quit;
```

However, nothing changes. As a result I get the code1 and code2 column to be populated exactly like the Code column from the initial dataset. I would really appreciate any help on this as regex is not my strong suit. I also put code1 = 'ERROR' and later on code1 = '0' in order to check if the code works.

It should be noted that I created up to code6 as a trial. I cannot know the exact number of codes per ID. However, I do know that the code must always  be one letter in combination with either one or two digits and it can also be in the form Z12-9 (so one letter followed by two digits, followed by a dash, followed by one digit).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using PROC DS2? Is that a requirement? A data step is fairly simple here.

Comment: It's not a requirement, it was simply copied from an older code base that I have used. But I do get your point :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering the regular expression part of this, your regex is wrong, and I think `prxposn` is probably also wrong.

`\w` matches numerics as well as alpha, so `\w+` will grab all of the string.  You need to either use `[A-Z]`, or use `\w+?` to use less aggressive matching to get only the single alpha-then-numeric set.

Also, the right method here is `call prxnext`, `prxposn` matches each bracket match *in the regex*, so 1 is the first one, 2 is the second one, but `(something)+` only is one bracket match. `call prxnext` will keep finding more matches of a single match and you can use that to grab the matching bits.

Again here is in simple data step, but DS2 would be similar.

```
data want;
  set have;
  rx = prxparse('/[A-Z]+\d+/ios');
  
  start = 1;
  
  do until (pos eq 0);
    call prxnext(rx,start,length(code),code,pos,len);
    if pos gt 0 then do;
      w = substr(code,pos,len);
      put w=;
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 3):

I find this a particularly good use case for `call scan`, regex isn't nearly as efficient.  Here I use `call scan` to find the "word boundary" of the (always single) letter, then grab it plus whatever's before the next letter (or end-of-word).

```
data have;
length code $20 ;
input id code $;
datalines;
101 K2K5K8F10F26F2 
102 L7P13P4 
103 L1
;;;;
run;
data want;
  set have;
  do count = 1 to countw(code,,'a');
    call scan(code,count,pos,len,,'a');
    w = substr(code,pos-1,len+1);
    output;
  end;
run;
```

I think this would work in DS2 just as well as the data step if that's a requirement.